# terminfo seems to not work in csh

Tags: linux, terminal, csh, tmux, terminfo

I want to use screen-256color term and my system does not have one, so I compiled it in my home dir. Following is my problem

```
xxxx: ~/.terminfo > tree
.
|-- s
|   `-- screen-256color
`-- x
    `-- xterm-256color

2 directories, 2 files
xxxx: ~/.terminfo > setenv TERMINFO ~/.terminfo
xxxx: ~/.terminfo > setenv TERM  screen-256color
csh: No entry for terminal type "screen-256color"
csh: using dumb terminal settings.
```

It seems that the system can not detect the screen-256color file?

Answer (score 4):

On most Linux's, terminfo has replaced termcap.  However, some were slow to replace termcap with terminfo for a few applications such as csh/tcsh (such as Slackware).  If that is the case, it is likely looking for an entry in /etc/termcap

You can check this easily by looking at the libraries listed for

```
ldd `which csh`
```